# Wordpress "Add new tag" button is not working

Tags: plugins, posts, tags

I really dont know where else to look at :(

When I try to create a new tag in wordpress from back end under post column, it wont save the tag. However when I tried to save a blank it prompts me an error as suppose to be..only major issue is- it is not SAVING AT ALL.

Following are the things I tried with no luck -

- Deactivated all plugins(although I have only 3 plugin though) and then checked but no luck.
- Firebug it for JS errors but NO JS errors though.
- I freshly re-installed/updated Wordpress core files to look if it missed something previously but no luck.
- Tried by setting it to true for error but no luck define('WP_DEBUG', false);

Let me know what else I can try apart from these things.

**FYI** -
I am testing the site on staging server so have URL something like this-

```
http://1XX.1XX.2XX.2XX:8XXX/
```

and this is what I set under WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) [although not very sure if this is actually has to do something with this or not]

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problem, maybe it's not js issue, but XML instead.
Check if there are white spaces at end of the files involved ( after the PHP closing tag "?>")
Hope it helps!

**UPDATE**

maybe ajax cross domain issue ( 307 Temporary Redirect ) last chance:
Set this entries on your .htaccess file

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(abc\.com)$" origin_is=$0 
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{origin_is}e env=origin_is
```

replace `abc\.com` with your actual domain. For eg: `(google\.com)`

Comment: hey thx for the response..which files I need to look in??

Comment: maybe i should ask first, but are you working on your own theme? first of all functions.php and eventually included files

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: Nope yet not resolved :'( which XML files i need to check though?

Comment: i'm trying to reproduce the error, is a server response with XML format.

Comment: open firebug console go to net -> XHR try to add a new tag, what's happen in console?

Comment: for "admin-ajax.php" status - "307 Temporary Redirect" Initiator - "http://sitelink/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

Comment: under XML it is throwing -> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal: